# Identify the customer IDs who have purchased all products

Tags: database

Now there is a scenario requirement as follows:

There are two tables in my PieCloudDB Database. A customer table that records the IDs of all customers and the IDs of the products they have purchased. And a product table that contains the keys of all products.

I want to know which customers have purchased all the products. (Example data)

Customer:

| customer_id | product_key |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 3 | 6 |
| 1 | 6 |
| 4 | 5 |

Product:

| product_key |
| --- |
| 5 |
| 6 |

Out：

| customer_id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 3 |

I tried this query, but it takes too long because my table contains a large amount of data.

```
SELECT 
cp.customer_id 
FROM 
  (SELECT 
   customer_id, 
   COUNT(DISTINCT product_key)  AS total_products 
FROM customer 
GROUP BY customer_id ) cp
JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_products FROM product) p 
ON cp.total_products = p.total_products;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: Ok,I'll edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, one of the approaches can be the following:

```
SELECT 
mainTable.customerId 
FROM 
(SELECT 
c.`customer_id` AS customerId, 
COUNT(DISTINCT(c.`product_key`)) AS distinctProducts 
FROM customer c 
GROUP BY c.`customer_id`) mainTable
WHERE 
mainTable.distinctProducts=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `product`)
```

The  `mainTable` picks out customers and total distinct products they have bought and you can check them with the number of products in product table.

Another approach can be using `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT c.`customer_id` AS customerId
FROM customer c
GROUP BY c.`customer_id`
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.`product_key`) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `product`);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful to you. You can try it in your PieCloudDB database.

```
SELECT DISTINCT customer_id
FROM customer cp1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM product
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM customer cp2
    WHERE cp2.customer_id = cp1.customer_id
    AND cp2.product_key = product.product_key
  )
);
```

Comment: This won't be so much of an optimized query. Try using `EXPLAIN` before your query.